# Лучший способ создать экспортируемый модуль в Angular 4 для подключения в другом проекте

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript, frontend, webpack2

Столкнулся с проблемами при освоении *Angular*.

Необходимо создать общий модуль с компонентами на *Angular*, для использования в других проектах. Другие проекты используют *Webpack* для билда. При попытке это сделать постоянно сталкиваюсь с проблемами.

Сначала пробовал сделать через *Webpack*. Первая проблема была в том чтобы сбилдить тайпинги в одном бандле, чтобы подключать `bundle.js` + `bundle.d.ts`. Нормального способа не нашел. Сделал доступным и поправил руками, но оказалось *Webpack* очень тяжело работает с модулями уже сбилженными вебпаком. Куча ошибок с модульностью и экспортами.

Попробовал сбилдить обычным компилятором тайпскрипта - проблема с темплейтами. Не смог найти `app.component.html`, а включать в проект еще и `html` не хочется.

В идеале, использовать что-то типа специфичных `type-loader` для *Webpack*, но для компиляции каждого файла отдельно. Не знаю как это сделать.

Занимаюсь этим всего неделю, может быть совсем не в ту сторону иду.
Спасибо за ответы!